# mex file compiled successfuly. DependencyWalker cannot find many of the dlls

Tags: c++, matlab, mex

I have compiled a mex file using MATLAB. I am having trouble since every time I try to run the code, MATLAB crushes.

I have tried using `feval()` function with a `mexhost` in order to separate the processes and debug, following [this guide](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/out-of-process-execution-of-c-mex-functions.html). When I am executing using `feval(mh,'functionName',input)`, all I am getting is:

> Invalid C++ MEX-file 'test_c'

However, when I am executing using `feval(mh,functionName,input)` I am getting an `nrhs` of size 0.

I have followed throw with [this guide](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/invalid-mex-file-error.html) and used the DependancyWalker utility to get the following result:
[image]

A lot of the DLLs are missing. Even the basic LIBMEX.DLL can't be found. Am I doing something wrong here? How do I debug?

Answer (score 1):

Probably some of MATLAB's folders aren't in your system path variable (`%PATH%` on Windows).

Comment: Is there any way of telling which folders? I have tried using the search option to find some of the DLLs in my PC, to no avail.